# Not bolding letters in md files when using **

Tags: markdown, readme

Since ** characters ares used to **bold** words in `MarkDown` files (example: **`**bold**`**)

How could I write a doble '*' charachter without bolding the upcoming text?

Example: """See foo **kwargs for more info""", not being kwargs in bold.

Comment: Did you try `\*\*`? Adding slashes in front of those characters should escape them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JMds.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kgRD.png

Comment: In most contexts I would mark `**kwargs` as code, either inline using backticks or a as a code block. Are you trying to do this while leaving it as plain text?

Comment: Both things work. Thanks to both of you!